# Убрать перевод строки

Tags: html

Что нужно сделать чтобы было так:

```
текст [картинка-ссылка] текст
```

а не так:

```
текст  
[картинка-ссылка]  
текст
```

У меня картинка-ссылка меняется при наведении курсора:

```
 <style>
   a.rollover {
    background: url(lglogo1.png);
    display: block;
    width: 89px;
    height: 29px; 
    padding:0px;
   }
   a.rollover:hover {
    background: url(lglogo2.png);
   }
  </style>
```

Строчка в тексте добавляющая картинку:

```
<a href="http://domain.ru/" class="rollover"></a>
```

дело в том что картинка выше текста когда она должна быть на ровне с ним

Comment: желательно увидеть полный html и css

Answer (score 1):

[**`background-position`**](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position)

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline;
```

Comment: почти сработало, только картинка пропала(

Answer (score 0):

У вас явно какие-то стили влияют на это. Потому как без единого стиля, [выглядит именно так, как вам и надо](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/KbnDM/)

Comment: более подробно описал проблему в вопросе

Comment: Тогда практически так, как предложил @Kamilplus только:

    display: inline-block;

Будет так, как надо.

Comment: хм, странно.. ничего не изменилось
в отличии от предложенного @Construct `ом картинка не исчезла но и осталась стоять на строчку выше

Comment: [Смотрите еще раз](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/KbnDM/1/). Всё работает. Поэтому возвращаюсь к своему первому предположению : "У вас явно какие-то стили влияют на это."

Comment: во втором примере вы разложили все по полочкам!
Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

inline-block - выход, но не кроссбраузерно, если можно обойтись без inline-block, то лучше так и делать, а сдесь я уверен можно, вы бы если есть возможность ссылку дали на ресурс я бы взглянул как можно иначе сделать.

Comment: пока что это не в сети интернет

Comment: @triplustri, не всё так печально. inline-block работает с багами в IE6 и IE7, но работает. В остальных браузерах и осле выше седьмой степени - всё гуд